# Como fazer input de dois itens relacionados em um dictionaries

Tags: python

```
    usuarios= {'user':[]}
    senhas= {'senha': []}

    #Menu cadastro 
    print("Se você já é cadastrado digite (1)")
    print("Se você não é cadastrado digite (2)")
    menu= int(input("Digite a opção:"))

    #Cadastro de usuário
    def cadastro():
        usuario_novo= input("Informe o nome de usuário desejado: ")
        senha_nova= input("Informe a senha desejada: ")


        usuarios['user'].append(usuario_novo)
        senhas['senha'].append(senha_nova)

        print("Cadastrado com sucesso!")

#Login   
def login():
    consultar= input("Informe o usuario: ")
    consultarV= consultar in usuarios['user']
    if consultarV == True:
        print("Usuário correto!")
    else:
        print("Usuário incorreto!")

    consultar_senha= input("Informe a senha: ")
    consultar_senhaV= consultar_senha in senhas['senha']
    if consultar_senhaV== True:
        print("Senha correta")
    else:
        print("Senha incorreta")
```

como faço pra relacionar as senhas com os usuários

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para relacionar os dados, basta utilizar a função `zip` passando como parâmetro os valores que estão dentro de suas listas. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
usuarios = {"user": ["Gabriel", "Vanessa"]}
senhas = {"senha": ["pato23", "gamer23_bot@senha"]}

for item in zip(usuarios["user"], senhas["senha"]):
    print(item)

# ('Gabriel', 'pato23')
# ('Vanessa', 'gamer23_bot@senha')
```

Você também pode utilizar o método de lista `index` para obter a posição do nome do usuário na lista que está na chave **user** e consequentemente, obter a posição da senha que está na lista de **senha**.

```
usuarios = {"user": ["Gabriel", "Vanessa"]}
senhas = {"senha": ["pato23", "gamer23_bot@senha"]}

nome_procurado = "Gabriel"
posicao = usuarios["user"].index(nome_procurado)
senha = senhas["senha"][posicao]
```

---

Se me permite dizer, não acho certo você criar um dicionário somente para usuários e outro somente para senhas. Você poderia em único dicionário guardar essas informações para ficar mais fácil, prático e organizado o dicionário. Exemplo:

```
registros = {"user": ["Gabriel", "Vanessa"], "senha": ["pato23", "gamer23_bot@senha"]}
```

Para facilitar mais ainda a manipulação do dicionário, você pode definir os nomes dos usuários como as **chaves** do dicionário `registros`, onde cada usuário terá um dicionário para guardar suas informações. Exemplo:

```
# Dentro do dicionário registros temos chaves que serão os nomes dos usuários, 
# e essas chaves guardarão outros dicionários contendo as informações de cada usuário.

registros = {
    "Gabriel": {"senha": "pato23"},
    "Vanessa": {"senha": "gamer23_bot@senha"}
    }

# Abaixo está um exemplo simples para você ver o quão fácil ficaria 
# o código com esse formato de dicionário acima. No exemplo abaixo, eu criei
# uma tela para redefinir senha.

nome        =  input("Digite seu nome: ")
senha       =  input("Digite sua senha: ")
nova_senha  =  input("Digite sua nova senha (Mínimo de 5 caracteres): ")

print("Verificando nome de usuário...")

if nome in registros:
    print("Verificando senha...")

    if registros[nome]["senha"] == senha:
        print("Logado com sucesso.")

        if len(nova_senha) > 5:
            registros[nome]["senha"] = nova_senha
            print("Senha redefinida.")
        else:
            print("A senha deve ter no mínimo 5 caracteres.")
    else:
        print("Senha inválida.")
else:
    print("Nome de usuário inválido.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Melhor forma de fazer isso é usando as propriedades de objeto do Python, que é a grande força da linguagem.
Para entender mais sobre como usar o python orientado para objetos recomendo essa série aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihKUUur4nxg&list=PLV7VqBqvsd_3yRYYWrHkziPL6izzrUIkp&index=11

O seu código escrito usando a orientação para objetos ficaria +- assim:

```
lista_usuarios = []

class Usuario():
    # Define as variáveis da classe (objeto) "Usuario".
    nome = ''
    senha = ''

# Cadastro de usuário
    def cadastro(self):
    # Define as duas propriedades do objeto 'Usuario'.
        self.nome = input("Informe o nome de usuário desejado: ") 
        self.senha = input("Informe a senha desejada: ")
    # Anexa um usuário particular já definido com nome e senha a uma lista de objetos do mesmo tipo.
        lista_usuarios.append(self)
        print("Cadastrado com sucesso!")
        return self # Retorna o objeto à função que chamou a definição.

# Verificação de senha
def verificar_senha(usuario_identificado): # Recebe um objeto 'Usuario'
    consultar_senha = input("{} informe a senha: ".format(usuario_identificado.nome))
    if consultar_senha == usuario_identificado.senha: # Verifica se a senha fornecida é igual a propriedade senha do usuario que foi fornecido pela definição.
        print("Senha correta")
    else:
        print("Senha incorreta")

# Login   
def login():
    nome_para_teste = input("Informe o usuario: ") 
    for x in lista_usuarios: # Aloca em x os usuários cadastrados.
        if nome_para_teste  == x.nome: # Verifica se a propriedade nome dos usuários é igual ao nome fornecido.
            print("Usuário correto!")
            verificar_senha(x) # Chama a verificação de senha para o usuário 'x'.
        else:
            print("Usuário incorreto!")

# Menu cadastro
menu = 3
while menu != 0:
    print("Se você já é cadastrado digite (1)")
    print("Se você não é cadastrado digite (2)")
    print("Digite zero para sair.")
    menu= int(input("Digite a opção:"))
    if menu == 1:
        login()
    if menu == 2:
        pessoa = Usuario() # Define a variavel 'pessoa' como do tipo 'Usuario'.
        pessoa.cadastro() # Como 'pessoa' é da classe 'Usuario' ela tem a definição de classe "cadastro()".
        verificar_senha(pessoa) # Chama a verificação de senha pro usuário recêm cadastrado.
    if menu == 0:
        for x in lista_usuarios:
            print('Usuário: {}, senha: {}'.format(x.nome,x.senha))
```

Comment: eu só nao entendi esse
" for x in lista_usuarios" 
de onde ele apareceu?

Comment: 'x' nesse caso é uma variável de auxilio para percorrer uma lista. O comando " for x in lista_usuarios" pega um por um os objetos dentro de 'lista_usuarios' e executa os comandos abaixo. Poderia usar " for usuario in lista_usuarios" / " for pessoa in lista_usuarios" / " for cadastrado in lista_usuarios" /etc. Mas é importante notar que esse variável vai ser local, definida somente dendro do loop 'for... in'. Usei um nome diferente justamente para ficar destacado a hierarquia da variável ou seja dentro de qual espaço do programa ela está definida. O vídeo que te passei explica bem essa questão.